# How can load time performance be increased when loading Script Libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, performance

Hopefully I am posing this question within the proper context.

I am loading some custom JQuery UI content and it is taking upwards of 453 milliseconds to load 1 script. 1 of which is a mini-fied version

To me that seems like a fairly long time considering all the other associated scripts, bootstrap and etc. that also needs to be loaded prior to rendering the page to the client.

[image]

I rarely run across this type of issue but when it happens its an absolute bear to deal with because I usually have to begin thinking about implementing wait overlays and other mechanisms to alleviate a potentially bad user experience due to extended load times.

So 2 questions here:

1. Are the load times for the libraries shown in the picture unreasonable or are those times fairly common? Considering there are no network issues in the equation
2. Aside from Script bundling and leveraging minified versions; are there any other available methods that can potentially assist to alleviate or minimize the script load times to squeeze better performance on page loads requiring those scripts?

I'm just fishing around a bit here to see how others may be dealing with this. Maybe there could be suggestions that I may not have considered.

"How are you loading your scripts":
 I am using the ScriptManager in this particular instance and also the ScriptBundler as shown below with the ASP.NET framework but I've also seen the issue using MVC although not as prevalent because of the model and alleviated postbacks.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>

<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Minimize your HTTP Requests & combine all related files into one file and that may help !

Comment: Alas the question is currently off topic at SO - but make sure to gzip the files

Comment: how are you loading your scripts? give us snippet of your implementation.

Comment: It really depends on the server performance. A dedicated server with a SSD will be much faster than a shared server with a mechanical drive.

Comment: Adding more to @JeremyThille words that it also depends on the client internet connection speed too.

Comment: Ok, so based on the comments so far. I suppose the methods I am already aware of are likely the extent of what can be done from a programming perspective. Many times I cannot control the internet connection speed nor the h/w unfortunately. I'll try the gzip and see what it gets me but I believe I went down that path before without much luck. Thanks guys